# Access value of private datagrid in NUnit - VB Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unit-testing, nunit

I want to Unit test a method in `NUnit` that uses the rows property of a datagrid. The method's result is based on the row count of a the datagrid. The grid is of course private and I don't have the option setting it public.

Thus, since I can't access the datargid from the test method, I cannot create test rows for checking my test cases.
Is there anyway I could mock the grid or any other clever technique for creating my test case, based on the number of rows of the grid?

P.S: I am looking for something, without reflection. Is it feasible or I am wasting my time?